# How to use SQLite on Ionic 4 / Capacitor / Electron application?

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, electron, ionic4, capacitor

I am using Ionic 4/ Capacitor to target Windows via the Electron option.
I need to manage heavy database on this application so i want to use SQLite.

I listed these potential solutions :

- Use `SQLite ionic native` plugin (@ionic-native/sqlite). It seems that it's not possible to use it on desktop.
- Use `capacitor-data-storage-sqlite` plugin ([github link](https://github.com/jepiqueau/capacitor-data-storage-sqlite)) but it's only for key-value usage and not for relational database.
- Use `capacitor-sqlite` ([github link](https://github.com/jepiqueau/capacitor-sqlite)) : only available on android and ios platforms

None of them solve my problem.

I found this topic on stackoverflow : [Can I call Ionic 4 / Capacitor Electron code from the Ionic part of the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976737/can-i-call-ionic-4-capacitor-electron-code-from-the-ionic-part-of-the-applicat)
Maybe it is a good solution, but it's necessary to prebuild sqlite package on each platform + create a bridge, point by point, between ionic app and electron part to manage database.
I think it's not the better way to use and maintain source code.

Do you have a good way to use sqlite relational database from an ionic 4 / capacitor / electron app please ?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Dev-kun : not for the moment. Let me know if you find one ;)

Answer (score 0):

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite is probably your answer. It should work on macOS and Windows.